# Delete phone number from Facebook account

Tags: facebook, notifications

I have taken my phone number off of my Facebook info page so they should have no record of it. However, I now have a different phone number and the person who now has my old # keeps getting notifications about my Facebook account and they are angry about it.  How can I get Facebook to *stop* sending all phone notifications?

Comment: I assume these are SMS notifications?

Comment: See here [How to adjust mobile push notifications](https://www.facebook.com/help/103859036372845/).

Answer (score 3):

The info page just shows which phone numbers you want your friends to see. You need to go to your Facebook settings https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=mobile and check if your old number is still associated there.

[image: Mobile Settings]

Additionally you can click "Lost your phone?" and hopefully that should log the user out.